# Is there a standard way to customize the deploy path in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm exploring the possibilities of [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) right now, and I'm at a slight impasse.  I want to be able to run two Spring Boot applications at once, both on the same server, but at different paths (one deploys on `/`, the other deploys at `/another-path`).

Because this is an embedded Tomcat instance running within Spring Boot, there's no configuration files available for me to change.

Is there a standard way to do this?  Is it *possible*?

Comment: Spring Boot applications run in their own JVM.  To get the behavior you ask for, you need both applications to be in the same JVM which is not what Spring Boot is designed for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Spring Boot comes with some pre-built property support. If you create an **application.properties** file, you can include:

```
server.port=<another port>
server.address=<another IP address>
server.sessionTimeout=<another timeout setting>
server.contextPath=/your-other-path
```

This can be in **application.properties** adjacent to your runnable JAR, embedded inside the JAR file, or simply applied as a **-Dserver.contextPath=/your-alt-path** with the java command. These are cascading, meaning you can embed one set of defaults inside the JAR, override with a local **application.properties** file, and then finally override **application.properties** with the -D options.

Comment: Ah, now it's coming back to me.  I remember this being discussed and demonstrated at the presentations.  Thanks!

Comment: One fine point @Makoto, Spring Boot doesn't support multiple apps running inside the same embedded container, which I'm not sure if that's precisely what you're asking. Each app runs in its own embedded container.

Answer (score 1):

As it uses an embedded tomcat you should be able to add a `/META-INF/context.xml` to each application which specifies the [path](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) (at least this should work for a normal tomcat).

That works for our normal embedded tomcat stuff, so I would expect it to work for Spring Boot as well.